# Image Processing using Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I currently have a web service that does as follows:
- User inputs image
- Web service launches a C program using OpenCV
- The program loads training data
- The program detects and recognises certain objects
- The program records these detections and recognitions in a MySQL database
- If the program has detected and recognised objects, it adds it to the training data

This program can take up to 1 minute to run per image. How could I structure Amazon Web Services to do this efficiently?

Comment: Could you give some further details on the relative time spent in each step?

Comment: Program loading training data at maximum would take 20 seconds (initially though less than 1 second), detecting and recognising objects takes about 1 minute, and the other steps would all be well below 1 second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coincidentally, AWS released a [detailed tutorial](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1602) about processing images, using EC2, S3, SimpleDB, and SQS. It should get you most of the way there.

Comment: In this tutorial, the graphic only has 1 EC2 instance, does this mean the web application and the image processing is done on the same instance?

Comment: Looks to be, yes, but there's no reason you couldn't pass calls between multiple machines. Image processing is computationally intensive. I would probably architect with that in mind, by using lightweight, dirt cheap instances for the webapp (which in your case sounds like a form post), and pass it to a more expensive machine with a boatload of CPU. You could even spin up that machine on demand, but of course that'll take at least a minute and not provide you with an opportunity cost advantage. It's all about what you want to pay.

Answer (score -2):

U can go for **step function** in aws  there u will see the process with one f